# CMS for existing site via REST API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest, drupal, content-management-system

I have an existing site built on Ruby on Rails. The site has around 20-30 pages. I am thinking about having a CMS to control the content that displays in each page.

I am thinking about setting up a Drupal instance and consume the content via REST API in the RoR site. Is this the right approach or is there an alternative approach?

This should be a common requirement for most of the sites out there but I don't find much information about this online. Is it because people setup their own CMS or is it because Drupal is not used for this purpose?

Answer (score 1):

There's no harm in consuming the CMS data through its REST API. If it works for you, then well and good. But this is not a popular approach as when you change content, you'd often want to change your styles too which is not easily achieved via REST API and that's why people often opt to use a whole page from CMS.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check out our CMS https://scrivito.com